# Mocking BouncyCastle classes - SecurityException

Tags: java, mocking, bouncycastle, spock

I am trying to write unit test for my class that's using BouncyCastle's `SignerInformation` - I wanted to mock an instance of it but trying to do so causes `java.lang.SecurityException`. Here's a simplified working example:

**SignerInformationConsumer.java**

```
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;

public class SignerInformationConsumer {
    public String interact(SignerInformation si) {
        return si.getDigestAlgOID();
    }
}
```

**SignerInformationConsumerTest.groovy**

```
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation
import spock.lang.Shared
import spock.lang.Specification

class SignerInformationConsumerTest extends Specification {

    @Shared
    SignerInformation si = Mock()

    def "should return valid array"() {
        given:
            SignerInformationConsumer test = new SignerInformationConsumer()
            si.digestAlgOID >> "aaa"
        when:
            String digest = test.interact(si)
        then:
            digest == "aaa"
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.1-groovy-2.4'
    testCompile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcpkix-jdk15on', version: '1.60'
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type

    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:140)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:346)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:161)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:355)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$ByteBuddyMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:108)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:65)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.createInternal(JavaMockFactory.java:59)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:40)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:51)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:296)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:286)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.MockImpl(SpecInternals.java:89)
    at TestTest.$spock_initializeSharedFields(TestTest.groovy:8)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking java.lang.ClassLoader#defineClass
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Direct.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:412)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.inject(ClassInjector.java:185)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:187)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:120)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4457)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4447)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:113)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$ByteBuddyMockFactory$1.call(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:110)
    at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:138)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation$SpockMock$bSXMi60o"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:898)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:668)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:761)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Direct.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:408)
    ... 22 more
```

Can you suggest some solution on how to mock this class or test the behaviour differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with signed JARs here. Assuming that you do not want to globally disable Java's security features and also do not want to create copies of all BouncyCastle JARs, removing their manifests, I will just show you a workaround.

The problem is that Spock mocks (others, too) are created in the same package as the original class. But the mock is unsigned code, thus the error message. Now you can just subclass the class to be mocked and mock that subclass instead. Just make sure the subclass has all necessary constructors from its parent if you need them anywhere in your test.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;

public class SignerInformationConsumer {
  public String interact(SignerInformation si) {
    return si.getDigestAlgOID();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation
import spock.lang.Specification

class SignerInformationConsumerTest extends Specification {

  static class SignerInformationMock extends SignerInformation {
    protected SignerInformationMock(SignerInformation baseInfo) {
      super(baseInfo)
    }
  }

  //SignerInformation signerInformation = Spy(SignerInformationMock, useObjenesis: true)
  SignerInformation signerInformation = Mock(SignerInformationMock)

  def "should return valid array"() {
    given:
    SignerInformationConsumer signerInformationConsumer = new SignerInformationConsumer()
    signerInformation.getDigestAlgOID() >> "aaa"
    expect:
    signerInformationConsumer.interact(signerInformation) == "aaa"
  }
}
```

A few words about your test:

- Don't use `@Shared` because tests should be independent from each other. You could bleed side effects from feature method A into B. Shared variables should only be used in very rare circumstances, e.g. if the object you create is very expensive with regard to time or resources. A mock definitely is not. So either create the mock right inside your feature method or, if the same mock definition is to be used by other feature methods, use a normal member variable without `@Shared`. You can ignore this advice, of course, but I still think you should follow it.
- Your test does not test the application, it only tests the mock. I hope that your real test case looks different because this test, even if I made it work for you, only checks that the stubbed result is as specified at the beginning of the test.
- The commented line in my code shows you how you can use a spy instead of a mock if you need to for any reason (e.g. you want to use the real object and just stub one or a few methods). In this special case you will need Objenesis as a dependency though, otherwise you will get an exception because there is no default constructor. Alternatively, you would have to create the spy and include constructor arguments.
- If `getDigestAlgOID()` is to be stubbed identically in each feature method, you can move the stubbing part from the feature method into the mock definition like this:

```java
SignerInformation signerInformation = Mock(SignerInformationMock) {
  getDigestAlgOID() >> "aaa"
}
```